# Peugeot 206 crashed repairing

Tags: repair, peugeot, peugeot-206

Recently I've crashed my peugeot 206 and because of my financial issues , I can't repair it right now .

The car moves fine and there isn't any engine issues only the front is damaged and pushed towards the engine a bit .

Here are the crash pics :

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Is there anything I need to check and consider to know that is it okay for the car to stay in the garage for at least 2 months or I need to repair it quickly and prevent other problem that may occur later on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say from your pictures as they are all from the top of the car, the really important views are underneath, however they aren't that important to give a reasonable answer. If the car is running and not leaking anything then it will be fine to leave it for a few weeks. The main consideration is the battery, in two months it will be flat and you may have to replace it, I suggest you get an inexpensive trickle charger to keep it fresh.

Comment: I do start the engine for 10 minutes every 3 days to keep the battery alive , do I still need a new battery after a while ?

Comment: No, you don't if you keep the battery charged by running the engine. You will waste fuel though, a trickle charger may be a cheaper option.